# phpunit and autoloader not working even with spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, web-applications, phpunit, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to get PHPunit working with an existing custom framework.  I've gotten some basic tests to work but when I try to hook a test up to my bootstrap code, none of my classes will autoload!  I've looked into the issue and changed my original __autoload to:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once APP_MODELS . "/$class_name.php";
});
```

This still works for standard web calls, but when I try to run code via PHPunit, I still get a class not found error.  Am I still doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Neeevermind, I was editing the wrong guy.  Problem solved!